# Understanding a C macro syntax and function

Tags: c

I have some trouble understanding a macro.

Since its propriorty code I cant share exact code. Thus, renaming and sharing.

The main idea is that server side code monitors the communication (data packets) and sets some status bits (to mark if data is received correctly).

In one of the code flow, I encounter nested for loops, which uses a macro at the end of each iteration of the 1st for loop:

```
for( msg_no=0U; msg_no<packet_num; msg_no++ )
{
    for( rec_no=0U; rec_no<current_rec_number ; rec_no++ )
    {
        SetError( ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE, current_rec_number, 
                ( current_rec_number<=TOTAL_RECORD_NUM )?0:1 );
    }
}
```

The current values(from debug session) of each variables are below:

```
packet_num = 1
ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE = 0 ( --> #define ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE 0 )
current_rec_number = 0
TOTAL_RECORD_NUM = 8 ( --> #define TOTAL_RECORD_NUM 8 )
```

The macro definition looks like this:

```
#define SetError(temp_1, temp_2, temp_3)    (temp_1)
```

I am not sure what exactly is set using this macro, or how this macro functions. The 1st parameter here is temp_1 which is replaced by ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE. So not sure what is returning or setting here.

Sorry if the information isnt enough. Please ask, if more information is required.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define SetError(temp_1, temp_2, temp_3)    (temp_1)` get 3 arguments and just produces the first between ()

so

```
for( msg_no=0U; msg_no<packet_num; msg_no++ )
{
    for( rec_no=0U; rec_no<current_rec_number ; rec_no++ )
    {
        SetError( ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE, current_rec_number, 
                ( current_rec_number<=TOTAL_RECORD_NUM )?0:1 );
    }
}
```

is in fact

```
for( msg_no=0U; msg_no<packet_num; msg_no++ )
{
    for( rec_no=0U; rec_no<current_rec_number ; rec_no++ )
    {
        ( ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

---

If you have gcc/g++ you can use the option -E to see the result after the preprocessing

```
/tmp % cat m.c
#define SetError(temp_1, temp_2, temp_3)    (temp_1)

for( msg_no=0U; msg_no<packet_num; msg_no++ )
{
    for( rec_no=0U; rec_no<current_rec_number ; rec_no++ )
    {
        SetError( ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE, current_rec_number, 
                ( current_rec_number<=TOTAL_RECORD_NUM )?0:1 );
    }
}
/tmp % gcc -E m.c
# 1 "m.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "m.c"


for( msg_no=0U; msg_no<packet_num; msg_no++ )
{
    for( rec_no=0U; rec_no<current_rec_number ; rec_no++ )
    {
        (ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE)
                                                              ;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it is `( ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE )`... btw where that  `;` went?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes I just fixed that

Comment: You are right. But, I dont understand its use case. If its (ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE) in a for loop, its not used anywhere to set or mark any bits of any status variable. Its a standalone macro.

Comment: @blackbug may be `ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE` is a macro too whose definition contains code doing 'something'  ? I cannot know that for you :-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the ';' is present in the source code so I doesn't disapear, you can see it too in the result of `gcc -E` even far of `(ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE)`

Comment: @blackbug may be _SetError_ is wrongly defined and must be `#define SetError(temp_1, temp_2, temp_3)    setError(temp_1)` or something like that ? Or it is wronly used and a form `SetError(...)` must not be used alone

Comment: @bruno no, the definition is as i posted above. And I cant find SetError anywhere in the entire codebase. Its a working software so I believe the basic definitions would be correct. I am using mex compiler with C setup. And debugging on visual studio. I will try compiling using MEX_COMPILE_FLAG and see if debugger can read this macro

Comment: @blackbug oh sorry I didn't see ERROR_COMM_01_FAILURE is 0, so yes is strange

Comment: Ah it was there, using mobile phone :)))

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the suggestions and info. I will post if I found something more about this macro. Till then I marked it solved. cheers!